# NSDate Math? Now and Fire timer in the future

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimer, nsdatecomponent

I have been racking my brains on this one looking for a quick solution.

I need to fire off a NSTime at a specific time based on the current time in a specific time zone.

For example, I get the current time in PST:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";

NSCalendar * cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PST"]];

NSDateComponents * comps = [cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
```

I see that the time is 2 (14) getting [comps hour] and I need to fire a timer at 2:30PM (14:30) on that day. I need help converting it back and doing the math to say how long it is before the timer fires. I will be setting up several different timers based on the current time. While I am looking at the time in PST I know that the timers and setting of the time is done in GMT. That's another twist...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you looking to always fire your timer at 14:30, or are you always wanting to fire in 30 minutes from now?

Comment: Fire it at 14:30 if the current PST time is before 14:30

Comment: The problem stems when I go over to the next day GMT since I'm on PST

Comment: So you already tried setting the components to 14:30 and setting your NSTimer and that didn't work?  Can you put that code up as well?

Comment: If you want to fire the timer 27 minutes in the future, that's 27 minutes in all time zones.  Simply calculate the time delta and set a timer to fire at the appropriate time interval from "now".

Comment: Here is a better example. It's 12:04PM PST and I need to fire a NSTimer at 14:30 PST and if its 15:20 I need to fire a time at 19:00. All PST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.. But thanks for the tips...

```
if ([date earlierDate:newDate] == date) // it is before 7AM... fire at 7AM
```

and so on....